# Subsurf-based modelling and deformation

Tags: unity, subdivision-surface

I'm using subsurf modifier for my models.
Following to some documentation, I put subsurf on the bottom of modifier stack for better deformation.

[Armature]
[Subsurf]

To use this model in Unity or other environments, subsurf modifier must be applied(or automatically applied when export as .fbx).
But this causes undesired distortion when I rotate bone in Unity.

I assume that's because modifiers priority is swapped.
In other words, this situation is equal to

[Subsurf]
[Armature]

in Blender.
What I want to know is how to keep smooth distortion out of blender(environment that cannot keep modifier stack information).

[image: The Left is good, the right is bad.]

thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the deformation you're seeing, the mesh, and the modifier stack?

Comment: I provide a picture in which the left is good, the right is bad.

Comment: Please understand that I don't have experience importing into Unity, but I'm curious what happens when you apply the mods manually and rotate the bone in Blender.  Do you see the same deformation as you do in Unity?

Comment: Yes. Both manual and automatic cause same deformation.